# Почему в OpenCV cv::Mat::data является указателем на тип uchar? C++

Tags: c++, opencv

Заметил такую штуку. В OpenCV существует огромное множество типов изображений, они отличаются числом каналов и типом значений внутри. Например обычное трехканальное rgb изображение может характеризоваться uchar'ом, т.е. содержать внутри значение от 0 до 255 (Т.е. каждый канал или цвет - это число от 0 до 255), или char'ом, но тогда значения будут от -128 до 127. Отсюда вопрос, почему cv::Mat::data всегда указатель на uchar? А если я открою изображение в режиме со знаком (char)? Что будет тогда? Если же data всегда от 0 до 255 (uchar), то зачем нужны все эти типы в OpenCV?

Comment: Ничего не будет, т.к. вы просто скастуете указатель одного типа на другой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data не всегда  от 0 до 255, достаточно привести в пример формат с 16-битными целыми `CV_16U` или 32-битными плавающими значениями `CV_32F`.

Использование указателя на байт удобно, т.к. байт является наименьшей адресуемой единицей.

В общем-то, наиболее общим указательным типом является бестиповый указатель `void*`, однако его всегда нужно приводить к конкретному типу, а вот для `uchar*` этого можно избежать в доброй половине случаев использования в OpenCV - как для матриц с байтовым монохромным пикселом, так и для цветных RGB, RGBA при использовании индекса с домножением на 3 или 4.

Comment: Но если data - это указатель на uchar, то как изображение может быть не от 0 до 255? Например 2-х байтовые изображения, получается, что на один канал будет выделено 2 элемента типа uchar?

Comment: На один канал один 16-битовый элемент CV_16U, при обращении через указатель просто приведёте тип к нужному. Заметьте, что обращение через указатель далеко не всем требуется.